# How to use only direct light?

Tags: rendering, light

I want to create a [viewshed analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viewshed_analysis) with Blender. Something like this:

[image]

I tried it using light in Blender Render and Cycles but I can't get it to work due to the light fall off. I have already set the light bounces to 0.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do that easier in a compositing step.

1. Choose whichever renderer.
2. In the [Rendering Tab](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/post_process/layers.html) of the Properties Editor, activate the [Shadow Pass](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/blender_render/settings/passes.html#render-passes-in-detail).

The shadow pass hold exactly that information: where light hits and where not. The intensity isn't relevant. It is also antialiased.

[image: enter code here]